# Django models - how to filter number of ForeignKey objects

Tags: python, django, database-design

I have a models `A` and `B`, that are like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  (...)

class B(models.Model):
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  (...)
  a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

Now I have some `A` and `B` objects, and I'd like to get a query that selects all `A` objects that have less then 2 `B` pointing at them.

A is something like a pool thing, and users (the B) join pool. if there's only 1 or 0 joined, the pool shouldn't be displayed at all.

Is it possible with such model design? Or should I modify that a bit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`extra`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none).

```
A.objects.extra(
    select={
        'b_count': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourapp_b WHERE yourapp_b.a_id = yourapp_a.id',
    },
    where=['b_count < 2']
)
```

If the B count is something you often need as a filtering or ordering criterion, or needs to be displayed on list views, you could consider denormalisation by adding a b_count field to your A model and using signals to update it when a B is added or deleted:

```
from django.db import connection, transaction
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete, post_save

def update_b_count(instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Updates the B count for the A related to the given B.
    """
    if not kwargs.get('created', True) or kwargs.get('raw', False):
        return
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        'UPDATE yourapp_a SET b_count = ('
            'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourapp_b '
            'WHERE yourapp_b.a_id = yourapp_a.id'
        ') '
        'WHERE id = %s', [instance.a_id])
    transaction.commit_unless_managed()

post_save.connect(update_b_count, sender=B)
post_delete.connect(update_b_count, sender=B)
```

Another solution would be to manage a status flag on the A object when you're adding or removing a related B.

```
B.objects.create(a=some_a)
if some_a.hidden and some_a.b_set.count() > 1:
    A.objects.filter(id=some_a.id).update(hidden=False)

...

some_a = b.a
some_b.delete()
if not some_a.hidden and some_a.b_set.count() < 2:
    A.objects.filter(id=some_a.id).update(hidden=True)
```

Comment: Too complex solution, while Django has annotations feature.

Comment: Incorrecte marked as correct solution. See solution by gravitron below.

Answer (score 152):

The question and selected answer are from 2008 and since then this functionality has been integrated into the django framework.  Since this is a top google hit for "django filter foreign key count" I'd like to add an easier solution with a recent django version using [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/).

```
from django.db.models import Count
cats = A.objects.annotate(num_b=Count('b')).filter(num_b__lt=2)
```

In my case I had to take this concept a step further.  My "B" object had a boolean field called is_available, and I only wanted to return A objects who had more than 0 B objects with is_available set to True.

```
A.objects.filter(B__is_available=True).annotate(num_b=Count('b')).filter(num_b__gt=0).order_by('-num_items')
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it is really slow (like using the "extra" in answer 1 was almost instant but with this it took each entry more than 5 seconds). Is there a way that is faster without dropping into raw SQL?

Comment: Sorry, I have not yet had to deal with a lot of data hitting my site so I haven't dealt with speeding this query up yet.  I would suggest caching the result and only running the query periodically.

Comment: Adding extra raw SQL "breaks" the idea of using an ORM

Comment: @llazzaro - no it doesn't. Django docs have never said "you shouldn't use SQL or you'll break the abstraction". If they had they wouldn't have let you do it. Of course you always avoid it, but sometimes you have to.

Comment: @Joe I never used the word "django" in my comment.

Comment: @llazzaro fine, but the question is about Django. And the answer you were commenting on was about Django.

Comment: This is just me complaining and questioning the usefulness of ORM DB abstraction stuff.  Personally, it's way easier to churn out a SQL query like `SELECT * FROM yourapp_a WHERE id IN (SELECT a_id FROM yourapp_b GROUP BY a_id HAVING COUNT(*) < 2)` than to decipher every individual framework's inane syntax for what should be a simple DB transaction.  I really think it's more of an aversion to learning/knowing SQL, which is unfortunate as it conforms so well across many DB platforms.  Just my two cents.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend modifying your design to include some status field on A.

The issue is one of "why?"  Why does A have < 2 B's and why does A have >= 2 B's.  Is it because user's didn't enter something?  Or is because they tried and their input had errors.  Or is it because the < 2 rule doesn't apply in this case.

Using presence or absence of a Foreign Key limits the meaning to -- well -- present or absent.  You don't have any way to represent "why?"

Also, you have the following option

```
[ a for a in A.objects.all() if a.b_set.count() < 2 ]
```

This can be pricey because it does fetch all the A's rather than force the database to do the work.

---

Edit: From the comment "would require me to watch for user join / user leaving the pool events".

You don't "watch" anything -- you provide an API which does what you need.  That's the central benefit of the Django model.  Here's one way, with explict methods in the `A` class.

```
class A( models.Model ):
    ....
    def addB( self, b ):
        self.b_set.add( b )
        self.changeFlags()
    def removeB( self, b ):
        self.b_set.remove( b )
        self.changeFlags()
    def changeFlags( self ):
        if self.b_set.count() < 2: self.show= NotYet
        else: self.show= ShowNow
```

You can also define a special `Manager` for this, and replace the default `b_set` Manager with your manager that counts references and updates `A`.

Comment: A is something like a pool thing, and users (the B) join pool. if there's only 1 or 0 joined, the pool shouldnt be displayed at all...
That's why I wanted to not include such status - would require me to watch for user join / user leaving the pool events. But, maybe that's the way...

Answer (score 1):

I assume that joining or leaving the pool may not happen as often as listing (showing) the pools. I also believe that it would be more efficient for the users join/leave actions to update the pool display status. This way, listing & showing the pools would require less time as you would just run a single query for SHOW_STATUS of the pool objects.