# Check queryset is empty in Django

Tags: python, django

Say I had a piece of code like:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Excludes any questions that aren't published yet.
        """
        all_entries = Choice.objects.all()

        if not all_entries:
            return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

I am trying to get all the choices from a question, and return a 404 if there are none available. However I have only managed to implement part of it and get the error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter'

This is taken from the very bottom of the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial05/) where it mentions

> For example, it’s silly that Questions can be published on the site that have no Choices. So, our views could check for this, and exclude such Questions.

Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT:**

I changed the code referencing "all_entries" with:

```
all_entries = Choice.objects.all().count()

if all_entries > 0:
    return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

but that simply returns all questions, whether they have choices or not...

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
       return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.choice_text
```

**EDIT For cms_mgr**

Basically I want to check that the number of choices associated with the specified question is empty. When I go to this link - `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/3/` I want to get the question from the id ('3') and check the number of choices it contains.

Comment: What's the `Question` model code look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to approach getting all questions if and only if they have related choices is to get a list of `Choices` rather than questions then evaluate your query against those. For example:

```
Question.objects.filter(pk__in=[x.question.pk for x in Choice.objects.all()])
```

The bit inside the square brackets is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). List comprehensions are really useful and worth getting to know. In the code above the list comprehension will evaluate first. What is basically says is 'for each `x` in `Choice.objects.all()` put `x.pk` in this list'. The queryset will then return every `Question` for which there exists at least one related `Choice`.

If what you want is a queryset of `Choices` for each `Question` then they are already available to you. For any instance of `Question`, we'll call ours `q`, you can get its associated `Choices` with `q.choice_set.all()`, which will return empty if there are none.

To implement: first change your `DetailView`'s name to avoid confusion with the generic one. Let's call it `QuestionDetailView`. Add a `context_object_name` to make your template more readable later. Don't tinker with the default queryset to exclude unpublished questions because the correct way to do this is with a [model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/managers/).

```
class QuestionDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'question'
```

In your template for that view the question's related choices will already be available to you with something like `{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}`. That `question` is called that because we gave it a `context_object_name` so you could use any name you like. Note there's no need for `()` after the `all` in a template.

If you need to do some other work with the choices before returning them to your template you can do that in the view. So, in your `QuestionDetailView` you could add:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # call the base implementation to get original context
    context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['choices'] = self.object.choice_set.all() # your question's choice set, to manipulate
                                                      # as you see fit
    return context
```

I'll explain what's happening here. This is adding extra context to what the view will return for your template to consume. The code I've written will just return all the question's choices so doesn't add to what was already there, but you can perform any other actions you care to. The modified choice set would then be available in your template as `choices` so you could do `{% for choice in choices %}`.

No matter what way you choose an empty choice set is possible and you can cater for it easily (`{% if choices %}` or `{% if question.choice_set.count %}` in the template, for example). You probably want to handle any empty queryset more elegantly than a 404 because you don't really want users being directed to error pages for a predictable result, such as an empty queryset.

Comment: What is 'x'? Does this look similar to what you were thinking?
Question.objects.filter(pk__in=[Question.id for x in Choice.objects.all()])

Comment: Thanks, this at least compiles now, but the number of choices returned seems to be only 2. I have 3 questions - one containing 3 choices, one containing 2 choices and one empty. I was expecting 5 choices in total. Also, is there a way of getting the choices by the question id from this list?

Comment: It does? Your code appears to get the total choices from all the questions. Getting a value of 2 confuses me as, for one thing, there are a total of 5 choices, and another, I need to get the number of choices for that specific question.

Comment: Oh, you're answer confused me when you said "...is to get a list of Choices rather than questions..". I must already have the question because "Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())" returns its choices. Somehow I need to get that question's id and then its choices from that.

Comment: Please see the Edit for you.

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning anything if all_entries is *not* empty. If a function doesn't explicitly return a value, Python returns `None`.

Comment: Thanks, that prevented the error, but now it displays the question, regardless of the number of choices.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not as easy as it may seem. You have to filter the Question queryset by their number of Choices, not check if Choices exist and then return a Question.

You should check out [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6205303/4015036) to see how you could accomplish that with annotation.

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way? I already have the Question object, can't you somehow just get the choices out of the object?

Comment: This is when you'd use `choice_set`. For any `Question` `q` its related `Choices` are `q.choice_set.all()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe worthwhile to mention there is a tutorial [part 7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial07/) later in this series, gives hint on the correct way to handle the following problem from root.

> For example, it’s silly that Questions can be published on the site that have no Choices. So, our views could check for this, and exclude such Questions.

I think the best way to fix it is to avoid creating "Questions have no Choices" in the first place (assuming no one is going to temper with database directly).
This tutorial teaches you how to modify the admin site page, where we should only allow admin to add Question with at least 2 Choices.