# Extra credit in Django tutorial

Tags: python, django

While going through the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/), I've decided to implement some "ideas for more tests" in part 5, namely

> For example, it’s silly that Questions can be published on the site that have no Choices. So, our views could check for this, and exclude such Questions.

I've implemented this check in **views.py** by changing the `IndexView.get_queryset` function as follows

```
def get_queryset(self):
    #Return the last five published questions with nonzero choice_set
    result = [];
    for q in Question.objects.all():
        if q.choice_set.count() > 0:
            result.append(q)
    return sorted( result, key=attrgetter('pub_date'), reverse=True )[0:5]
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this? Something along the lines of `return Question.objects.filter(choice_set.count()>0).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]` (which does not work for probably obvious reasons).

**EDIT 1**
Another possible answer would be `return Question.objects.filter(pk__in=[x.question.pk for x in Choice.objects.all()]).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]` (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058604/check-queryset-is-empty-in-django?rq=1)). It still won't allow exclusion of questions with a single choice, like @catavaran suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude all questions where `choice=None`, and it will exclude all questions without choices:

```
qs = Question.objects.exclude(choice=None).order_by'(-pub_date')[:5]
```

Or you can use `choice__isnull=False`, but this can return duplicate entries. Use `.distinct()` to counter that:

```
qs = Question.objects.filter(choice__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It kinda worked, but now I am getting 4 identical questions ("What's new?") on the index page, I do have only 1 question with 4 choices...

Comment: As suggested in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26978102/filtering-out-choiceless-polls-in-the-django-tutorial-causes-polls-in-the-index?rq=1), duplicate results can be fixed by adding a call to `distinct()`, e.g. `Question.objects.filter(choice__isnull=False).distinct('question_text').order_by('-pub_date')[:5]`. However, it seems that my backend DB (mysql) does not support this operation: _Exception Value: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend_

Comment: @DeLorean88 You'll have to call `.distinct()` without any arguments. I've added another method that won't return duplicate entries and won't need `.distinct()`. For very small databases the second method is significantly faster, but I don't know how it will scale, as `.distinct()` can usually be a performance problem in large databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Question.objects.annotate(num_choices=Count('choice')) \
                .filter(num_choices__gt=0).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

In fact poll with only one choice does not makes sense too :-)  So it is better to use `filter(num_choices__gt=1)` instead of `filter(num_choices__gt=0)`.